# An analog of C++ FQA for C#

Tags: c#

I have found [C++ FQA Lite](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/) very edificatory and would like to read more criticism. Could you recommend me something similar but concerning C#, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a document. Most of the problems mentioned in the C++ FQA are not relevant for C# (and other languages).

You might want to read [Common programming mistakes for .NET developers to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid).